# Android AIDL oneway method blocked when trying asynchronous RPC using remote service

Tags: android, multithreading

I was trying to make asynchronous RPC using keyword **oneway** in .aidl file. My test project contains 3 parts:

- AIDLAsynchronousClientActivity.java
- AIDLAsynchronousRPCService.java
- IAsynchronousInterface.aidl

The service is in **a remote process** and registered in AndroidManifest.xml as follow:

```
<service
        android:name=".threading.AIDLAsynchronousRPCService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":test">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="hahaha.hehe.heihei2" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

IAsynchronousInterface.aidl contains keyword **oneway**:

```
interface IAsynchronousInterface {
    /* hide basic methods */ 

    oneway void getThreadNameBlocking();

    oneway void getThreadNameUnblock();
}
```

The implementation of the methods above in AIDLAsynchronousRPCService.java:

```
    IAsynchronousInterface.Stub mBinder = new IAsynchronousInterface.Stub() {
        CountDownLatch mLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        /* hide basic methods */ 

        @Override
        public void getThreadNameBlocking() throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "*************blocking...");
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                mLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "*************blocked");
        }

        @Override
        public void getThreadNameUnblock() throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "#############unblocking...");
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());

            mLatch.countDown();

            Log.d(TAG, "############unblocked");
        }
    };
```

And the activity will do:

1. bind the service(AIDLAsynchronousRPCService), get the IBinder returned when service connected
2. call ***getThreadNameBlocking()*** above
3. call ***getThreadNameUnblock()*** above
4. restart from step 2(loop)

Then the application executing as follow:

1. the RPC call loop worked well in Activity, no blocks
2. the service was blocked, nothing was executing after calling ***getThreadNameBlocking()***

I thought the service should not block cause I commented the *mLatch.await();*, and the log was printed as follow:

```
10-11 23:24:30.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocking...
10-11 23:24:30.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_1
10-11 23:24:30.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocked
10-11 23:24:31.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: #############unblocking...
10-11 23:24:31.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_2
10-11 23:24:31.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: ############unblocked
10-11 23:24:31.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocking...
10-11 23:24:31.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_2
10-11 23:24:31.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocked
10-11 23:24:31.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: #############unblocking...
10-11 23:24:31.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_1
10-11 23:24:31.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: ############unblocked
10-11 23:24:31.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocking...
10-11 23:24:31.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_1
10-11 23:24:31.524 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocked
10-11 23:24:32.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: #############unblocking...
10-11 23:24:32.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_2
10-11 23:24:32.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: ############unblocked
10-11 23:24:32.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocking...
10-11 23:24:32.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_2
10-11 23:24:32.024 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocked
10-11 23:24:32.525 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: #############unblocking...
10-11 23:24:32.525 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_1
10-11 23:24:32.525 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: ############unblocked
10-11 23:24:32.525 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocking...
10-11 23:24:32.525 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_1
10-11 23:24:32.525 1933-1950/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: *************blocked
10-11 23:24:33.026 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: #############unblocking...
10-11 23:24:33.026 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: Binder_2
10-11 23:24:33.026 1933-1951/com.example.yu.testapplication:test D/RPCService: ############unblocked
```

There were 2 binder threads working in the remote process. So I thought the remote process call would be managed by Android System as above: **RPC calls would be on different binder threads**. But the fact was the blocking call blocked the whole process. I am confused about and willing to know the mechanism behind this kind of RPC call in Android.

Comment: `Binder` transactions are executed in a small pool of `Binder` threads: `Thread[Binder_1,5,main]`, `Thread[Binder_2,5,main]` etc, see `IBinder` documentation, it says: `"""The system maintains a pool of transaction threads in each process that it runs in. These threads are used to dispatch all IPCs coming in from other processes. [...]"""`

Comment: @pskink That means one blocking RPC call should not block the whole process, there should be other binder threads there. But my service in remote process blocked after one method call.

Comment: ok, i see your point now, it seems you cannot block binder thread if it its used in one-way transaction: you have to use some worker thread to do things like that...

Comment: and if you want to make some generic way of dispatching remote AIDL calls, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pskink/c28b2021e8b30f4e1ffab0013f8f0780)